# So strange issue in django's template

Tags: python, html, django

In the django's action method, i give a parameter `deletable_objects` to the template, it works. The code is

```
   deletable_objects, perms_needed, protected = get_deleted_objects(
            queryset, opts, request.user, self.admin_site, using)
   In the webpage, is shows as below:
```

[image]

In the above, the value of  deletable_objects is `[u'Task: <a href="/admin/ticket/task/3/">dasdsa</a>']`, this is sent  to `{{ deleteable_object|unordered_list}}` in template file as a variable, and i detect the web resource, it is as below:

[image]

But in additional, i set deletable_objects to `[u'Task: <a href="/admin/ticket/task/3/">dasdsa</a>']`  clearly and send it to the template . This time it is not working.
The web page is as below:

[image]

And i also detect its web resource as below:

[image]

My question is what is the differnce between the two kinds of scenario, the value of the parameter `deletable_objects` are the same (one is sent by variable and one is set value before sent by variable). In the web resource, the `<li> </li>` contents are the same, but  why the result are different, from the highlight color or the picture we can see that.

**Update**
I set the {{ deleteable_object|safeseq|unordered_list}} to fix this issue, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, django does not parse HTML in strings passed to the template; this is to prevent security problems by injected tags.

There are various ways to get around this; one is to [mark the string as safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#std%3atemplatefilter-safe) in the template.

Comment: so should i set the {{ deleteable_object|unordered_list}} to {{ deleteable_object|unordered_list|safe}} in template? I have tried it but it dose not work